# $y'$ at $(0, 0)$ of $x^2 = y^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

After noticing that implicit differentiation allows you to find an expression for a derivative for relations that aren't even functions (ex. $\frac{dx}{dy}$ where $x$ is defined by $y = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2+cx + d$), I have been playing around with similar relations, such as $x^2 = y^2$. Implicitly I can find that 
$$x = y \cdot y' = \pm x \cdot y'$$
According to this, $y' = \{1, -1\} $ when $x \neq 0$ and $y' = \Bbb R $ when $x = 0$. However, looking at the graph, I am not convinced why $y'$ should be $\Bbb R$ instead of $\{1, -1 \}$.
[image]

Instead, I would intuitively expect $y' = \{1, -1\}$ for all $y$, or perhaps algebraically $(y')^2 = 1$. (But I couldn't get my derivative into this form without division by $0$). Looking at the graph, I would find it more natural to draw tangent lines at $(0, 0)$ with slope $1$ or $-1$ compared to, say, $\pi$ or anything else which satisfies $0 = 0\cdot y'$ . I would appreciate if someone could explain the discrepancy!

Comment: To me, it looks like the derivative isn't defined at (0,0) because it would depend on the direction from which you approached the origin.  In a hand-wavy way, this is very similar to y=|x|, which you may or may not already know is commonly used to illustrate these sorts of issues.  I'm sure a "proper" mathematician can give you a proper answer (hence why this is only a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful about when implicit differentiation works. It relies on the implicit function theorem:

> If $F = F(x,y)$ is a continuously differentiable function of two variables, then the level set $\{(x,y) \mid F(x,y) = 0\}$ implicitly defines $y$ as a function of $x$ in a neighborhood of a point $(a,b)$ provided that $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(a,b) \not= 0$.

In your example $F(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$ and $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0) = 0$ so the implicit function theorem doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify: is the converse true then, that if y' is defined, then it is impossible that ∂F/∂y = 0?

Comment: No. Modify your initial example to $F(x,y) = x^3-y^3$.

Comment: Note that even when this condition ($\partial{F}/\partial{y}\ne0$) is not met, there is a weaker version of the theorem that still holds, such that *if* there is a way for $y$ to be a function of $x$ consistent with the equation $F=0$ (and assuming that $F$ is a differentiable function of $x$ and $y$, as it is here), then $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$. In the case of the original question, this tells you that $0\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$, which is true but useless.

Comment: @UmbertoP. So how would I tell a difference algebraically between cases such as $x^2 - y^2$ and cases such as $x^3 - y^3$?

Comment: (To avoid giving the false impression that the Implicit Function Theorem is a trivial corollary of my weaker version: it's not. The formula $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{\partial{F}/\partial{x}}{\partial{F}/\partial{y}}$ when $\partial{F}/\partial{y}\ne0$ *is* a trivial corollary, but you still have to assume that there is some way to express $y$ as a function of $x$ consistent with $F=0$. The IFT additionally states that you *don't* have to assume this; this must possible, at least locally, near any individual solution $(x=a,y=b)$ of $F=0$. That's the deep part of the IFT.)

Answer (score 0):

Talking about $y'(x)$ presupposes that you have a *function* $y=y(x)$ to begin with. But there is no neighbourhood of the origin where the equation $y^2=x^2$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$ (since for each $x \neq 0$ you have *two* choices of $y$ which satisfies that equation). So the question is meaningless.

(By the way, if $y(x)$ is a real-valued function, then $y'(x)$ is a real-valued function too, so it's also meaningless to say that the value $y'(0)$ is a *set* like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\{-1,1\}$. If $y'(0)$ exists, it's a *real number*.)